# How to extract the "Link" header from the Github API using Ruby and HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-api, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to interact with the Github API. Github API responses are paginated. The pagination is included in the "Link" header of an HTTP response. [See here.](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)

I can't figure out how to access the Link header information of an HTTParty object, and therefore how to extract the pagination information.

I would like to understand how to do this without requiring additional gems.

My code so far:

```
  def ghapi path, query
    query.merge!({
      "per_page" => 100
    })
    return HTTParty.get("https://api.github.com/#{path}", query: query, headers: {
      "Authorization" => "token #{session[:token]}",
      "User-Agent" => "WDIDC"
    })
  end
```

`ghapi.headers` is evidently how one should access the header information. However, this does not include the relevant information. Here is the information it does include, with sensitive information excluded:

```
{
"server": [
"GitHub.com"
],
"date": [
"Sun, 05 Jul 2015 18:52:04 GMT"
],
"content-type": [
"application/json; charset=utf-8"
],
"content-length": [
"2"
],
"connection": [
"close"
],
"status": [
"200 OK"
],
"x-ratelimit-limit": [
"5000"
],
"x-ratelimit-remaining": [
"4870"
],
"x-ratelimit-reset": [
"1436125019"
],
"cache-control": [
"private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60"
],
"x-oauth-scopes": [
"gist, repo, user"
],
"x-accepted-oauth-scopes": [
""
],
"vary": [
"Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP",
"Accept-Encoding"
],
"x-github-media-type": [
"github.v3; format=json"
],
"x-xss-protection": [
"1; mode=block"
],
"x-frame-options": [
"deny"
],
"content-security-policy": [
"default-src 'none'"
],
"access-control-allow-credentials": [
"true"
],
"access-control-expose-headers": [
"ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval"
],
"access-control-allow-origin": [
"*"
],
"strict-transport-security": [
"max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload"
],
"x-content-type-options": [
"nosniff"
],
}
```

I can see that `Link` is included in `access-control-expose-headers`, but that doesn't contain any actual information...

Comment: Are you sure that actual request contains a Link header? `Content-Length: 2` would suggest that you aren't getting anything back worth paginating.